# Nulling %al register before calling print

Tags: c++, assembly

Considering the [code](http://goo.gl/Hlxt0Q):

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  printf("null");
  return 0;
}
```

Why the assembly is:

```
main:                                   # @main
    pushq   %rax
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    xorb    %al, %al
    callq   printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rdx
    ret

.L.str:
    .asciz   "null"
```

What's the `xorb %al, %al` for? I know that `%al` is a lowest 8 bits of `%rax` register.

Comment: Have a look at http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2012/11/23/x86-64-assembly-language-tutorial-part-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the sysv abi calling convention, before calling varargs functions the `al` register should be set to the number of vector registers used for passing arguments. In this case that's zero, and xor is a common idiom for zeroing a register.

If you are interested in the calling convention, read the aforementioned abi doc.

Comment: And can you show an example, when the `%al` would not be zeroed?